# Google Apps Script Custom Menu / createMenu not displaying in Slide when presentation opens

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Does createMenu work differently for slides than it does for spreadsheets?

Is this a bug or is something wrong with my code? Should it be reported?

SIMPLE TEST - - - - - - - DOES NOT CREATE MENU ON OPEN FROM DRIVE OR REFRESH

```
function onOpen() {
  console.log('In onOpen' );
  
  const pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slideSet = pres.getSlides();
  
  let ui;
  try {
    ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
    console.log('getUi succeeded' );
  }  catch (e)  {
    console.log('caught in getUi: ', e );
  }
  
  try {
    ui.createMenu( 'Ask ?')
      .addItem('BE1', 'BE1') 
      .addToUi(); 
  }  catch (e)  {
    console.log('caught in createMenu: ', e );
  }
  
console.log('    after create menu');
  // let result = ui.alert('sample title', 'Please click "ask?" to begin.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);  
}
```

For this one there is no AUTH problem as there is almost no code.

Manifest

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

If you are curious the function called from the menu - BE1

```
/**
 * Create a new square textbox, using the supplied element ID.
 */
function BE1 () {
  let pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let slideSet = pres.getSlides();
  let shape = slideSet[0].insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 200, 300, 60, 60);
  let textRange = shape.getText();
  textRange.setText('Hello world!');
}
```

It really looks like create menu does not work upon slide presentation open or refresh despite Google documentation. Is this a bug? Can someone who knows how please report it?

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

Presentation That does open window.

```
function onOpen() {

  let ui = SlidesApp.getUi();

  let pres;
  let slideSet = [];
  try {
    pres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    slideSet = pres.getSlides();
  }    catch (err) {
    console.log('get active presentation err: ', err);
  }
  
    SlidesApp.getUi()
      .createMenu( 'Ask ?')
      .addItem('BE1','BE1')
      .addToUi(); 

}
```

Manifests:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Error when loaded from drive: get active presentation err:  { [Exception: Authorization is required to perform that action.] name: 'Exception' }

If you stop the program because of the error, the menu is not created. If you run from the script editor you do not get the authorization error.

Comment: The exact same onOpen, create menu and cache of separate spreadsheet is working in a script bound to a spreadsheet. The only difference is this one is bound to a slide deck.

Comment: @Cooper wanted me to investigate triggers. I view my triggers and I have none. In the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting I read "To authorize the script, open the Script Editor and run any function. The authorization prompt appears so you can authorize the script project. If the script contains new unauthorized services, you must re-authorize the script.' This does not happen. When onOpen is run in the editor no auth dialog is presented, the menu is create, etc.

Comment: Started over with a clean slide with nothing on it but a title text box. Created a menu in onOpen with one function. I can run the onOpen and the function from the script editor but onOpen does not run when the slide set is loaded and the function does not run from the menu. Error Script function not found: function BE1 () { ....

Comment: Try using and installable trigger. Inotherwords a trigger that you install yourself

Comment: Are you suggesting moving createMenu out of onOpen and putting a trigger associated with onOpen to run a separate createMenu function? How will this change the fact that when the menu is displayed clicking a function from the menu does not find the function. Again create a trigger to be called by the menu to call the function?  None of this is needed in spreadsheets. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use an installable trigger instead of a simple trigger because simple triggers can't perform operations that require permission.  So rename the trigger something else like onMyOpen() and install it programmatically or using the script editor.

Comment: Can you point me to an example. I just found "Since we want our custom menu item to appear when the sheet first loads, we will use the onOpen(e) function trigger. The onOpen(e) trigger runs automatically when a user opens a Sheet, Doc, Slide, or Form that they have permission to edit. Note that the trigger only appears on a Form when editing it."  https://www.christopherenea.com/post/custom-menu-google-sheets-docs-slides-forms Everything says this should work.

Comment: The installable onMyOpen(e) trigger runs automatically when you open the spreadsheet too.  But it also allows you to do operations that require permission

Comment: Look at [ScriptApp.newTrigger()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

Comment: You can also just go to the triggers page on the new editor and create it right there.

Comment: onOpen is the function to run but there is a warning "this project contains one or more functions with the same name. Choosing one of these functions will result in undefined behavior"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events shows authMode 
A value from the ScriptApp.AuthMode  
enum - LIMITED
source - A Presentation object, representing the Google Slides file to which the script is bound.
user - A User object, representing the active user, if available (depending on a complex set of security restrictions). amin@example.com 
Does this mean 'auth' is only allowed to be 'limited'?

Comment: Slides does not mention 'installable' like forms, docs, sheets, and maybe others

Comment: @Tanaike wrote "But at Google Slides, unfortunately, in the current stage, the OnOpen event trigger cannot be used as the installable trigger." in Jan 2020 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990535/can-i-use-slides-api-to-add-an-agree-to-terms-dialogue-before-allowing-viewer You seem to have used slides. Has anything changed? Can I use an 'installed' trigger onOpen to replace the simple trigger of the onOpen function? How? The add a trigger menu does not seem to allow anything but timed triggers.

Comment: I'd go with what Tanaike says.

Comment: I have doubts about the completeness of the support for slides in Google script. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659469/can-google-slide-modaldialog-html-javascript-run-server-side-code-environment-a

Comment: I don't have enough points to offer a bounty. Someone! Create a presentation (one slide) add an onOpen with createMenu. Does the createMenu result in a menu when you open your presentation from Drive or refresh while looking at it?  Does the onOpen work if you run inside the new or legacy editor? @tanaike what is wrong?

Comment: I forgot.  What is the question?

Comment: @Cooper Does createMenu work differently for slides than it does for spreadsheets? Can the onOpen createMenu work when slides presentation is opened from drive or refreshed. It always works when run from the script editor. It sometimes runs when slides presentation is opened but I cannot figure out why sometimes and not others.

Comment: I think SlidesApp.getUi().createMenu() is only available in the editor not once the presentation starts.  If you're doing something that requires permissions then you will have to use an installable on open and you won't want the name it onOpen().  I usually name it onMyOpen() but anything is okay except for onOpen() because that automatically works with simple triggers and that may result in getting double triggered.

Comment: So in a nut shell once the presentation starts the only interactive control you have is from the slides controls.  But I don't use slides much.  Is it your expectation that you should have additional control.  I find that things change so fast at Google it's hard to keep up with all the new features. So I could be wrong.

Comment: I copied onOpen logic and made onMyOpen. I made it an installable trigger. Nothing changed. Still no menu on open or refresh. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus implies createMenu is available for slides can someone pls report or find prob @the master

Comment: I do not know how you can tell if the trigger was executed. there is nothing in the execution logs. the onOpen runs in exec.logs show 'simple trigger' Exception: Authorization is required to perform that action. at onOpen(onOpen:4:26). All functions run without error or prompt for authorization from the script editor. @tanaike

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus states createMenu is available for slides. @Tanaike wrote "But at Google Slides, unfortunately, in the current stage, the OnOpen event trigger cannot be used as the installable trigger." in Jan 2020 stackoverflow.com/questions/59990535/  WHAT IS WRONG?

Comment: Buganizer: 178637299 Google Apps Script Custom Menu / createMenu not displaying in Slide - auth problem - created

Comment: I think I already made it clear that I don't think that you can create a menu on the presentation.  So I'm not interested in creating a bug report.  It's your problem you report it.  So I don't think it's a bug in your code.  It's possibly a misunderstanding of what's  possible.

Comment: Buganizer 178637299 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178637299 Maybe they think a strange workaround is ok - at least they should fix the documentation to say custom menus only work on slides if you catch and ignore an unspecified authorization problem which you cannot fix because it is 'UNSPECIFIED'.